# KDE 5.4 new application launcher

Tags: kde5

I have just upgraded my Kubuntu 15.04 to KDE5.4, but cannot find the new application launcher. Does anyone know how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Application-Launcher in the control-panel and select "Alternatives"

Even though I still recommend a [different method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740024/where-did-search-and-launch-layout-go-in-kde-plasma-5/747144#747144) this would be the recommended way to swift within the given opportunities.