# Where did "Search and Launch" layout go in kde plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, kde5, kubuntu-netbook

I don't see the **Search and Launch** layout under KDE 5 ? What package do I need to install in KDE 5 to get it ? I already tried installing plasma-netbook, but I did no get **Search and Launch** any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean KRunner? Or do you mean the appearance as menu-choice? My answer covers both, as this was not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

***plasma-notebook*** desktop is not available in Plasma-5. It is discontinued, and development in this direction has ceased.
See for yourself -> [package-search @ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plasma-netbook&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

BUT - there is something similar (or even better):

called ["Alternative Application Launcher"](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.4.0/)
(25.Aug.2015, introduced with Plasma 5.4.0)

[image: Plasma-screen-dashboard]
<sub>(source: [kde.org](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.4/plasma-screen-dashboard-2-shadow.png))</sub>

If you want to test this, but keep your old Launcher, just unlock your Mini-programs (right-click on Desktop surface), then add an additional Control-panel (select: empty one).

Make the most of it (click on "hamburger-symbol"):
Move it to the left side of the Desktop, shrink/expand it to the desired height and width. Just use the enhanced panel options for this (little arrows).

Then  add mini-programm Categorie: Program-Launchers – you have a choice of four. Pick the right one.

Since it was always interesting to me to use variant methods, I've done more enhancements to this new & empty control-panel:

Added another mini-program "Applications-symbols-only". So when you start a program, the symbol-only appears there. If you then do a right-click on the symbol, you can decide to keep it there permantely (even if the program is not active). This is the fastest way for me to start my favoured apps. Another adoption was selected from enhanced adjustments-menu (hamburger-symbol): "permanetly fade-out"

*If you can't get what you want, you've got to take what's there.* Hoping this helps. Last not least, you always have the option to use [***KRunner***](https://web.archive.org/web/20191215220935/https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kde-workspace/plasma-desktop/krunner.html). Just press ALT+F2 – If you want this on your Desktop, there's a Mini-Program called "Search"